# Application that allows me to switch tasks with the click of a button

Tags: windows, software-development

I often work on different tasks that I have to switch between. This usually entails me opening certain URL's, applications, and closing the windows from my previous task.

Example:
Working on Application 1 I need:
Postman, Docker Desktop, and GoLand

Working on Application 2 I need:
Pycharm, a browser window open to a certain website, and a terminal window

Are there any applications that have this functionality?

Comment: It is built in to Windows 10, MacOs and most Linuxes.  What specifically do you need that is different?

Comment: Are you referring to the desktop switcher? I'm looking for something that fully closes the applications that aren't being used.

Comment: OK. I've seen that done on Linux.  If I can remember where...